# Criteria for querying two related tables

Tags: select, abap, opensql

I got my select statement like this right now:

```
  SELECT pernr reinr pdatv pdatb accdt pdvrs abrec FROM ptrv_perio
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_ptrv_perio
WHERE ( abrec EQ '2'
        AND pdatv GE pa_begda
        AND pdatb LE pa_endda )
OR    ( abrec EQ '3'
        AND accdt GE pa_begda
        AND accdt LE pa_endda ).
```

The thing is the attribute `accdt` from my second condition is in another table. Is there a way I can get it and directly use it in the select statement?
The problem I got is, that I can't get the value before the select, because I get the right travel ID just in that select.

I hope I was able to explain my issue. Thanks for any hints! :)

Comment: I'm a bit of a beginner with that. And I wasn't really sure if I could use that here because I only use this value from another table as a condition not as result of the select statement.

Comment: @Dyrdek I think you should try to describe your problem a bit broader

Comment: @LPK ok I try to make it more clearly. I want to select travels from table A which are in state '2' or '3'. The state '2' travels need to be in a period of time which I can get from table A where I'm selecting from. But the travels with state '3' need to be in a period of time which I only get from table B.

So my question is: How can I select from table A while using a criteria from table B?

Comment: Whats the actual name of `Table B`?

Comment: Thanks LPK for your help. :) Right now I got a hint and solved it with the following code:
`SELECT p~pernr p~reinr p~pdatv p~pdatb p~accdt p~pdvrs p~abrec
    FROM ptrv_perio AS p INNER JOIN ptrv_head AS h ON p~reinr = h~reinr
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_ptrv_perio
    WHERE ( p~abrec EQ '2'
            AND p~accdt GE pa_begda
            AND p~accdt LE pa_endda )
    OR    ( p~abrec EQ '3'
            AND h~dates GE pa_begda
            AND h~dates LE pa_endda ).`


Sry couldn't display it better :/

Comment: @Dyrdek If its works - you should post it as an answer that everybody else can see it too ^^

Comment: @LPK ... You're totally right^^ give me a second I'll post it :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code solved my issue:

```
SELECT p~pernr p~reinr p~pdatv p~pdatb p~accdt p~pdvrs p~abrec
FROM ptrv_perio AS p INNER JOIN ptrv_head AS h ON p~reinr = h~reinr
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_ptrv_perio
WHERE ( p~abrec EQ '2'
        AND p~accdt GE pa_begda
        AND p~accdt LE pa_endda )
OR    ( p~abrec EQ '3'
        AND h~dates GE pa_begda
        AND h~dates LE pa_endda ).
```

I'm selecting from table p while on criteria in the OR-Statement comes from table h.
Hope this will help somebody besides me :)